# How to determine if cp -u actually copied the file?

Tags: cp, timestamps

I'm looking for a concise way to check if a file was copied using `cp -u`.

I have a little shell script which updates quite a number of files. At the moment the script `echo`es a little message for each file which gets copied.

Now I want to change the script in such a way that the `echo` only gets executed when the file actually was updated. I've checked if `cp -u` returned an error code if it didn't copy the file, but this isn't the case.

Is there a better way than manually comparing the timestamps of the files?

Comment: `if cp -uv source destination; then echo copied; else echo not copied; fi`didn't work ?

Comment: How come it didn't return a return code?

jpkroehling@cupuacu ~ $ cp -u nginx.conf nginx.conf.copy

jpkroehling@cupuacu ~ $ echo $?

0

jpkroehling@cupuacu ~ $ cp -u nginx.conf nginx.conf

cp: ‘nginx.conf’ and ‘nginx.conf’ are the same file

jpkroehling@cupuacu ~ $ echo $?

1

Comment: Ok, I give up in trying to get it printing nicely: http://pastebin.com/Bz4n8MVW

Comment: It always returns 0, even if the file wasn't copied. At least on my system it does.

Comment: For the record, the output I added on pastebin is from Fedora 20.

Comment: @jpkrohling: in second case you tried to copied nginx.conf to nginx.conf and not to nginx.conf.copy.

Comment: Well, that was the point. I was forcing an error, to check if the return codes were different when it can and when it can't copy :)

Comment: I'm not sure how this relates to my question. I hoped `cp -u` would return an error if `cp -u a b` doesn't update the file, because `b` already is up to date. Your example isn't related to this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if [ "$(cp -uv source destination)" != "" ]; then echo copied; else echo not copied; fi
```

**Update**

Match "->" in cp's verbose output. It only occurs if it could be successfully copied and if your filenames do not contain "->".

```
if [[ "$(cp -uv source destination)" =~ \-\> ]]; then echo copied; else echo not copied; fi
```

Comment: I'm kinda ashamed that I didn't thought of this. Thank you!